# b-nav-form won't stack with vertical navbar and instead renders horizontally

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to develop a Wiki Layout for our documentation, the issue is that when vertically orientating the nav, the inline form does not follow the vertical styling and instead renders next to the nav.

```
<div class="border-right">
            <b-navbar toggleable="md" type="light">
                <b-navbar-toggle target="nav_collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
                <b-collapse is-nav id="nav_collapse">
                    <b-navbar-nav vertical class="bd-sidebar">
                        <b-nav-form>
                            <b-form-input v-model={this.keyword} placeholder="Search by keyword..."></b-form-input>
                            <b-input-group-append >
                                <b-btn on-click={this.clearModel} variant="secondary">Clear</b-btn>
                            </b-input-group-append>
                        </b-nav-form>
                        <WikiNavItem contents={this.availableContents} layer={0} classes={this.classes} />
                    </b-navbar-nav>
                </b-collapse>
            </b-navbar>
        </div>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
(I have omitted content for security reasons)
[image: Result of issue]

Comment: could you add a screenshot of the result that you get ?

Comment: @boussadjra image has been added.

Comment: i tried your code snippet [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nr99nqk2qm) and i get the input and the button and when i resize the screen the humburger menu will be shown and the form will be hidden, what you want exactly

Comment: i think you want to get the humburger menu and the form aligned horizontally in the same row

Comment: The hamburger menu on a mobile display is working fine, the issue is that I want the form as part of the vertical navbar, aligned vertically with everything else on desktop, which at the moment, it seems to be in a separate column :)

Comment: i understood that you want to get your form under the nav-bar items

Answer (score 0):

The way i fixed it was extremely simple. I added a `<div>` around the nav-items and the form and it stopped the strange css occurrence taking place.

```
<b-navbar toggleable="md" variant="light" type="light">
                <b-navbar-toggle target="nav_collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
                <b-collapse is-nav id="nav_collapse">
                    <b-navbar-nav vertical class="bd-sidebar">
                        <div>
                            <b-nav-form>
                                <b-input-group>
                                    <b-form-input v-model={this.keyword} placeholder="Search by keyword..."></b-form-input>
                                    <b-input-group-append>
                                        <b-btn on-click={this.clearModel} variant="secondary">Clear</b-btn>
                                    </b-input-group-append>
                                </b-input-group>
                            </b-nav-form>
                            <WikiNavItem contents={this.availableContents} layer={0} classes={this.classes} />
                        </div>
                    </b-navbar-nav>
                </b-collapse>
            </b-navbar>
```